# Juju can't connect to environment

Tags: juju, maas, environment

I have been trying to run `juju status -e maas` but it keeps giving me the error

```
 2013-08-12 10:00:48,301 INFO Connecting to environment...
2013-08-12 10:00:48,357 ERROR Cannot connect to environment: Unexpected HTTP 401 trying to GET http://10.168.71.151/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?filename=provider-state&op=get
and it goes on down...
```

I am currently following the tutorial for UbuntuCloudInfrastructure, done everything till the above commands.

Comment: Could you please add in your question the link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

The [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure) you mention is outdated, try following [this one instead](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-maas.html), but start from scratch, running `rm -fr ~/.juju/environments*` first. Make sure you change the necessary settings in the `environments.yaml` file `juju generate-config` created, in the configuration of the **maas** sample environment.